# Minimizing ellipsoid over intersection of ellipsoids

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

Let's say I want to minimize a quadratic form $\sum_{j=1}^n c_jx_j^2$ (all $c_j$ are positive constants), which corresponds to an $n$ dimensional ellipsoid, over the outer part of the intersection of some given ellipsoids, i.e., minimize subject to the constraints $x^TA_jx \geq 1$, $j=1\ldots m$, where $A_j$ are given positive semidefinite matrices (thus making our region an intersection of ellipsoids). Are there any analytical results for these type of problems? Maybe not for general $A_j$, but at least for some? By analytical I mean "not numerical solutions".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minimize *what*? Minimize $n$-volume? $(n{-}1)$-surface area? Diameter? 

Comment: What is hier fa.?

Comment: I want to minimize the weighted sum of squares subject to those constraints. Geometrically, it corresponds to finding the smallest ellipsoid where each axis is scaled by $c_j$.

Answer (score 1):

There are, you should look at 'Semidefinite Programming':

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming

EDIT:

See Pag 58 of L. Vandenberghe and S. Boyd, “Semidefinite programming,” SIAM Rev.,
vol. 38, pp. 49–95, 1996. regarding results about the problem.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of sdp, but as far as I see, there are not many exact results for sdp, or I'm wrong? Couldn't find many in the literature. 

Comment: You should try to define more 'exact results'. 

From my point of view you might need to consider whether or not the semidifinite relaxation of your problem leads to a rank-one solution of the problem (otherwise, you will just get a lower bound of the solution). See L. Vandenberghe and S. Boyd, “Semidefinite programming,” SIAM Rev., vol. 38, pp. 49–95, 1996." for more info.


Comment: Since your domain is not convex, I m not sure how SDP can help...

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference mikitov. I have seen this paper before. So basically you say I should solve an sdp over the matrix $X = xx^T$, but relax $X$ so that it can be any positive semidefinite matrix of rank at least 1? So if the solution is an $X$ of higher rank, then the best thing I can do is to give a lower bound?

Comment: Yes Igor, the constraint region is highly non-convex. However, my simulations show that for certain structured $A_j$, there are finitely many $x$ appearing when the $c_i$ are varied. This somehow seems possible if we think about the geometry in the problem. The optimal $x$ is obtained by looking at all points $kx$, $k>0$, on the ellipsoid $\sum_j c_jx_j^2 = 1$ and choosing the $x$ in our region with largest such number $k$. In a way, the optimal $x$ should then be located on as many ellipsoids as possible.

Comment: Yes:

i) Your problem as it is, is non-convex
ii) Semidefinite programming relaxation can give you an approximate solution of the problem (since you are dropping the rank-one constraint).
iii) There might be the case where ALWAYS the semidefinite relaxation gives a rank-one solution. In that case, the solution to the semidefinite relaxation is the optimal value of your problem. Results about this are derived via studying the dual problem of the semidefinite relaxation.


Comment: Ok, so I relaxed the rank 1 constraint and used sedumi (a Matlab semidefinite programming package) to search for the optimal $X$ for different values on $c_j$. It always gives me the same matrix that is not rank 1. So this is unfortunate then for theoretical analysis? The fact that it is the same matrix, can that be used somehow? Maybe to try and find the best rank 1 matrix that is somehow "closest" to this higher rank matrix (that would probably also just be an approximation I guess)?

Comment: Yes, use $\X \approx \lambda_{\text{max}}uu^T$ where $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ is the maximum eigenvalue with u eigenvector. There are other approximations but I barely remenber them...

Comment: Yeah ok. However, I am actually interested in the optimal solution. It turns out only finitely many optimal $x$ occur. I wonder whether similar problems have been studied before. 